# Distribution of sum of exponentials

Tags: self-study, distributions, convolution, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent and identically distributed exponential random variables with rate $\lambda$. Let $S_2 = X_1 + X_2$.

**Q:** Show that $S_2$ has PDF $f_{S_2}(x) = \lambda^2 x \text{e}^{-\lambda x},\, x\ge 0$.

Note that if events occurred according to a Poisson Process (PP) with rate $\lambda$, $S_2$ would represent the time of the 2nd event.

Alternate approaches are appreciated. The approaches provided are commonly used when learning queueing theory & stochastic processes.

---

Recall the Exponential distribution is a special case of the Gamma distribution (with shape parameter $1$). I've learned there is a more general version of this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72479/177387) that can be applied.

Comment: This question is a very special case (and one of the simplest possible examples) of a sum of Gamma distributions.  (The Exponential is a Gamma distribution with a shape parameter of $1.$)  Thus, you could apply any of the answers at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479.

Comment: Thank you. I was unaware of [that more general question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/72479/177387), though I did know the Exponential is a Gamma distribution with a shape parameter of 1. I hope you'll agree this Q/A is ok as-is and shouldn't be deleted. This is a very frequent question in some engineering disciplines and is certainly more accessible than jumping straight into adding Gamma distributions.

Comment: @whuber I've updated the question specifically mention the more general question. Thank you.

Comment: For the reasons you gave, and because you have offered a clear account of solutions that work specifically in this case, I have not voted to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: @whuber Thank you. I'll go with whatever you & the community think best. It was a honest mistake -- I didn't see the other post.  FWIW, I've updated the question a bit more to highlight some context for this approach (queueing theory & stochastic processes).

Comment: I think the voting on your question and your answer has clearly indicated what the community thinks of this thread. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Conditioning Approach**
Condition on the value of $X_1$. Start with the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $S_2$.

$\begin{align}
F_{S_2}(x) &= P(S_2\le x) \\
&= P(X_1 + X_2 \le x) \\
&= \int_0^\infty P(X_1+X_2\le x|X_1=x_1)f_{X_1}(x_1)dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^x P(X_1+X_2\le x|X_1=x_1)\lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x_1}dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^x P(X_2 \le x - x_1)\lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x_1}dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^x\left(1-\text{e}^{-\lambda(x-x_1)}\right)\lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x_1}dx_1\\
&=(1-e^{-\lambda x}) - \lambda x e^{-\lambda x}\end{align}
$

This is the CDF of the distribution. To get the PDF, differentiate with respect to $x$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3320600/572874)).

$$f_{S_2}(x) = \lambda^2 x \text{e}^{-\lambda x} \quad\square$$

This is an Erlang$(2,\lambda)$ distribution [(see here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).

---

**General Approach**
Direct integration relying on the independence of $X_1$ & $X_2$. Again, start with the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for $S_2$.

$\begin{align}
F_{S_2}(x) &= P(S_2\le x) \\
&= P(X_1 + X_2 \le x) \\
&= P\left( (X_1,X_2)\in A \right) \quad \quad \text{(See figure below)}\\
&= \int\int_{(x_1,x_2)\in A} f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)dx_1 dx_2 \\
&(\text{Joint distribution is the product of marginals by independence}) \\
&= \int_0^{x} \int_0^{x-x_{2}} f_{X_1}(x_1)f_{X_2}(x_2)dx_1 dx_2\\
&= \int_0^{x} \int_0^{x-x_{2}} \lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x_1}\lambda \text{e}^{-\lambda x_2}dx_1 dx_2\\
\end{align}$

Since this is the CDF, differentiation gives the PDF, $f_{S_2}(x) = \lambda^2 x \text{e}^{-\lambda x} \quad\square$
[image: Figure]

---

**MGF Approach**
This approach uses the [moment generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) (MGF).

$\begin{align} 
M_{S_2}(t) &= \text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t S_2}\right] \\ 
&= \text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t(X_1 + X_2)}\right] \\
&= \text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t X_1 + t X_2}\right] \\
&= \text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t X_1} \text{e}^{t X_2}\right] \\
&= \text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t X_1}\right]\text{E}\left[\text{e}^{t X_2}\right] \quad \text{(by independence)} \\
&= M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(t) \\
&= \left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right)\left(\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-t}\right) \quad \quad t<\lambda\\
&= \frac{\lambda^2}{(\lambda-t)^2}  \quad \quad t<\lambda
\end{align}$

While this may not yield the PDF, once the MGF matches that of a known distribution, the PDF also known.

Comment: You wrote both the question and the answer. What is your point, if I may ask?

Comment: @Xi'an, I thought SE encouraged asking the question and answering it...I can screenshot where SE seems to encourage that for you if you want.  I've seen a lot of basic questions repeatedly asked and I've been thinking about posting some specific approaches to refer people to.   I wasn't able to find something like this and I can refer people to this for a variety of things.  If the CV community really hates this post that much, I will voluntarily delete it.

Comment: @Xi'an, Respectfully, I believe you both asked and answered a question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122917/when-if-ever-is-a-median-statistic-a-sufficient-statistic).

Comment: @Xi'an You may wish to read https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I don't have enough karma to comment but i think this is a worthwhile comment so I post here. For the General Approach, can you show the steps (or provide a proof) going from the double integral to the final expression. I derived myself and get the same answer as wolfram. [Link to Wolfram Answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=double+integral&assumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22DoubleIntegral%22,+%22integrand%22%7D+-%3E%22%5Clambda+e%5E(-%5Clambda+g)+*+%5Clambda+*+e%5E(-%5Clambda+h)%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22DoubleIntegral%22,+%22intvariable1%22%7D+-%3E%22g%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22,+%22DoubleI

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: about MGF approach: can you actually derive pdf from MGF rather than moments?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: in (I) I'm a bit confused about the condition $X_1=x_1$, because $X_1$ is a continuous rv. Shouldn't it be $X_1 \leq x_1$?

Comment: @Alex good question. I wasn't thinking about getting PDF analytically from MGF. Instead, if you identify the MGF, then you've solved the problem (see my edit).

Comment: @Alex you are wise to pay attention to such details. However, the integral is permitting the condition $X_1 = x_1$ without violating rules on continuous RVs since it is iterating across a step size of $dx$ (from a Riemann sum perspective).  Since the integration is pushing $dx \rightarrow 0$ in a limit sense, I believe the equality is correct.  If I altered the condition to be $X_1\le x_1$, I'd have to adjust the expression.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan thanks, for $X_1$ I think it's my confusion. The expressions$P(X<x) = \int_{0}^{x} \lambda e^{-\lambda x_1} dx_1$ are equivalent, but $P(X_1=x_1) \equiv 0$, so the notations $P(S<x|X_1<x)P(X_1<x)$ and $\int_{0}^{x}P(S<x|X_1=x_1)f(x_1)dx_1$ shoud be equivalent too,right?

Comment: @SecretAgentMan: can you also confirm that the condiitionality $P(X_1+X_2<x|X_1=x_1)$ allows us to replace $X_1$ with $x_1$ and then by independence $P(X_1<x -x_1|X_1=x_1)=P(X_1<x-x_1)$