# Prove that the sum of exponential random variables is a gamma distribution

Tags: exponential-distribution

I tried to prove using the convulution approach but it didn't work

Comment: show us your workings so far. The site supports $\LaTeX$

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: A partial answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/371768/distribution-of-sum-of-exponentials

Comment: Because exponential variables are a special case of Gamma variables, your question is answered in the generalization at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72479.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Remember that if $X\sim \Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ then X has a moment generating function given by $M_x(t)=(\frac{\beta}{\beta -t})^{\alpha}$ , $t<\beta$.

Asssume that $X_1,X_2,......X_n$ are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables. Let $Z=\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$, try to find $M_z(t)=E(e^{tZ})$